# How to make delayed DELETE SQL query?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I need to delete rows from table 14 days after the DELETE query has been made. Is it possible to do this using MySQL?

Comment: A schedueld task/script. Or add a `fldValidUntil` to your logic.

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: Not much of an answer and more a workaround: Instead of deleting the rows, you could "flag" them with a deleted-date. When selecting the rows you want to work with, you could simply add a condition, that the deleted date should be empty or less than 14 days away.

Comment: @Evan: I disagree. This indeed *is* an answer and a very good one at that. (And one could always add a process to physically delete such flagged rows at regular or irregular intervals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html) to schedule a query or a stored routine to run [at an arbitrary point in time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html):

> This is an example of a minimal `CREATE EVENT` statement:
>
> ```
> CREATE EVENT myevent
>     ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
>     DO
>       UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
> ```

Please mind, [the Event Scheduler is disabled by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler).